# Find text offset into document for DOM attribute

Tags: php, dom

How can I find the offset of a particular node or attribute using the PHP DOM extension (or another extension or library if necessary).

For example, say I have this HTML document:

```
<html><a href="/foo">bar</a></html>
```

And using the following code (with appropriate modifications):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
foreach($nodes as $href) {
    // Find start of $href attribute here
    echo $href->something;
}
```

I'd expect to see the output 15 or something to that effect, to indicate that the attribute starts at character 15 into the document.

There seems to be the method `DOMNode::getLineNo()` which returns the line number – this is similar to what I want but I can't find an alternative for the general offset into the text.

Comment: First of all, you need to realize that there is no 1:1 connection between the source code, and the resulting DOM. Many _different_ HTML input strings could result in the exact same DOM tree. For that reason, I am amazed that something like the mentioned `DOMNode::getLineNo` even exists; but as the comments in the manual say, it appears to be buggy to begin with. This feels a bit X/Y-problemy ... what do you actually needs this for, resp. what are you trying to achieve here in the end?

Comment: Why would you need to know? It seems unimportant. The DOM is a structured data format. Line numbers, character numbers are not really relevant, due to the structuring. You don't need them in order to find information.

Comment: Trying to build a high-performance system that can replace arbitrary nodes/attributes in a HTML document. If I can store where they are located, and I'm sure that the string I am using to replace is well-formed in the context of where it's situated, I can swap them out with string manipulation much more quickly than parsing, adjusting the tree, and serializing.

Comment: Well as CBroe points out, there's no guaranteed mapping between an element's position in the DOM and its position in the underlying file, and the library doesn't attempt to measure that, so I think anything you try, even if it's available, is likely to be unreliable at best. Perhaps it's possible to fork the library and get it to record where it finds each node in a given source file and expose that information.

Comment: Is that necessarily true? I don't think it'd be unreasonable to expect a tool that validates an XML document against a schema to not be able to tell you what line or position your document fails to meet the schema. In such a case the tool would need to retain that mapping. Perhaps there's no way in the PHP DOM extension but I'd be surprised if no parsing tool tracks this information.

Comment: For instance, the jsdom library for Node can track this information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

Comment: Assuming `DOMNode::getLineNo()` isn’t as buggy as the (older) comments in the manual suggest, perhaps you could use that to get the line number first - and then only search inside that line for the correct starting position yourself using other means? If you’re eventually gonna be loading your document from physical files, then `file()` would give you the “line array” to work with, otherwise if it is actually string based, you could still explode that into lines first.

Comment: Looks as though XML Parser (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) has a few more details, but even `xml_get_current_column_number()` only indicates the start of the element and not the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the attribute you want,

- replace its value to a unique value, that you will never see in the document
- dump the DomDocument to html again
- search for the unique value `s position in the string

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html><a href="/foo">bar</a></html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');

$mySecretId = 'abc123';
foreach($nodes as $href) {
    $href->value = $mySecretId;
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo strpos($html, $mySecretId) . "\n";
```

"**strpos**" will give you the first occurrence of the replaced value, which is the position you want.

Note flags "LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED" and "LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD", more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php).

If you want to find all positions of the matched elements, do:

```
foreach($nodes as $href) {
    $previousValue = $href->value;
    $href->value = $mySecretId;
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    echo strpos($html, $mySecretId) . "\n";
    $href->value = $previousValue;
}
```

Comment: The positions won't be exact since in most cases the length of `$previousValue` and `$mySecretId` are different. This can be circumvented by extending the length of `$mySecretId` to the same as given in `$previousValue` - however when `$previousValue` is too short it will lead to wrong results again

Comment: @OliverHader I do not think that this is a problem, since what is needed is the start position of the attribute value and also after finding the position for each attribute, it is resetting its value: "$href->value = $previousValue;", so that its length does not affect the next attribute position.

Comment: Jannes Botis, sorry, my fault. I overlooked that the node-list iteration is still in place. So, your example should work as well. However, there might be a side-effect since `$dom->saveHTML();` sanitizes malformed markup (e.g. additional superfluous spaces in the original HTML). Thus, using the determined offset positions on a sanitized HTML should work. +1

Answer (score 2):

### Assumptions

The following is based on some assumptions:

- `a.href` attributes are the only candidates that shall be handled - in case it shall be more the used regular expression pattern might become (too) complicated
- `a.href` attributes are always encapsulated in double quotes `"` and the value of the attribute node must not be empty
- in case `a.href` attributes occur multiple times in the very same node, the last occurrence takes precedence

### Code using `preg_match_all` with offset-capture

```
<?php
// define some HTML, could be retrieved by e.g. file_get_contents() as well
$html = <<< HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<a href="https://google.com/">Google</a><div><a href=
"https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a></div>
<A HREF="https://google.com/" href="https://goo.gl/">
Google URL</a>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

// search href attributes in anchor tags (case insensitive & multi-line)
preg_match_all(
    '#<a[^>]*\s+href\s*=\s*"(?P<value>[^"]*)"[^>]*>#mis',
    $html,
    $matches,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);

$positions = array_map(
    function (array $match) {
        $length = mb_strlen($match[0]);
        return [
            'value' => $match[0],
            'length' => $length,
            'start' => $match[1],
            'end' => $match[1] + $length,
        ];
    },
    $matches['value']
);

var_dump($positions);
```

will output the position information like the following (*note: the last position uses the second `href` attribute which has been defined twice for the very same anchor tag*)

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(4) {
    'value' => string(19) "https://google.com/"
    'length' => int(19)
    'start' => int(49)
    'end' => int(68)
  }
  [1] => array(4) {
    'value' => string(26) "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    'length' => int(26)
    'start' => int(95)
    'end' => int(121)
  }
  [2] => array(4) {
    'value' => string(15) "https://goo.gl/"
    'length' => int(15)
    'start' => int(183)
    'end' => int(198)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't developers use regex to parse html...  `$html = <<< HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<a href="www.ref.com#Kowalczyk" data-polishref="Kowalczyk">Referee #1</a><div>
<a href="www.ref.com#Jørgen" data-danishref="Jørgen">Referee #2</a></div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;`  Regex can work well- enough when you have reasonable control over the input, but not without.  We could go back and forth in a fix-it-break-it war (which I don't have time for, and I know a wordboundary would tidy things up) but my advice is to use a dom parser because they are better than simple regex.

Comment: ...not to mention single quoting.  Though you state in advance that your pattern does not accommodate this.

Comment: @mickmackusa Breath easy, I don't see a reason for you overreacting. I provided an alternative thought on the issue and adjusted the pattern accordingly to match you example. The assumptions in the beginning of my answer stated already what you just repeated concerning the single quote.

Comment: I'm not overreacting about anything.  It is important that all future researchers understand the silent impacts of using regex when dom parsers should be used.  I love regex (more than I should), but it is not always the best tool.

Comment: I agree on that, and it's true that the regexp I provided is not complete. So feel free to vote down my answer...